# Creating an HTML link is creating unexpected results

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, href

I need help figuring out why it is when I add a link in this code that it is altering my entire div block.

This is what the page looks like:

[image: Leaderboard page]

As soon as I make the text a link, it adds about 8px to the bottom (notice how the image is smaller than the div block).

What can I do to make this look like all of my other blocks?

**Update:** I believe I found the code that is causing the problem, it is in the CSS of the body. There is a style that has line-height at line-height: 1.625; - when I delete this, it fixes the issue. But now I am wondering how can I remove this code for my page, without effecting the rest of the site?

Here is the problem CSS:

```
body {
color: #3B3F42;
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 1em;
line-height: 1.625;
}
```

And here is the rest of the coding

```css
    .ratingWrapTopRated {
      background: #fff;
      width: 100% !important;
      height: 90px !important;
      margin: 0 auto;
      display: table;
      font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .cigarImage {
      background: #fff;
      color: #fff;
      display: table-cell;
      line-height: 0;
      width: 90px;
      padding-right: 4px;
    }
    .cigarName {
      background: #ff5100;
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle;
      word-spacing: 6px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 1.2em;
      padding: 0px 3px 0px 3px;
    }
    .numericalScoreTopCigars {
      background: #000;
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
      width: 25%;
      display: table-cell;
      font-size: 4.9em;
      letter-spacing: 3px;
      vertical-align: middle;
      font-weight: bold;
      border-left: 4px solid;
      border-color: #fff;
      line-height: 0;
    }
    a.ratingsLink:link {
      text-decoration: none;
      background: #ff5100;
      color: #fff;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
      word-spacing: 6px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 1em;
      padding: 0px 3px 0px 3px;
    }
```

```html
 <span class="ratingWrapTopRated">
    <span class="cigarImage hidebuttons"><img class="alignnone size-thumbnail wp-image-2352" src="http://cigardojo.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/padron-serie-1926-150x150.jpg" alt="Padron Serie 1926 No. 9 Maduro" width="150" height="150" /></span>
<span class="cigarName shortenText"><a class="ratingsLink" href="http://cigardojo.com/?p=1019">Fuente Fuente OpusX XXX Belicoso</a></span>
<span class="numericalScoreTopCigars">96</span>
</span>
```

Comment: The snippet looks fine. What is wrong?

Comment: You may need to post more of your CSS & HTML.  This code renders without any margin or padding like your dropbox image shows.  More code will help.

Comment: Can you post it in fiddle so we can emulate it?

Comment: Here it is on jsFiddle and it looks fine, I don't know why it gets messed up on my page... - http://jsfiddle.net/ga0bye93/

Comment: You should make a much simpler test case. It may help you narrow down the problem, and it will make it much easier for people to answer.

Comment: Use Developer Tools in Chrome(f12) of Firebug for Firefox. Use these to inspect the element you have added and the styles applied to it. Use this as the start point to debug/modify your CSS

Comment: You can try an in-line style to set line height to normal, for your specific div and avoid changing the CSS file.